# Not able to create Javadoc using Ant

Tags: java, ant, eclipse-plugin, build-process, build-automation

I am trying to build my project using Ant. While creating javadocs, I am getting one error as shown below :

If error is not clearly visible in below image refer this :

```
[javadoc] javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "E:\junoWrkspace\StrutsHelloWorld\src\com\igate\resources\ApplicationResources.properties"
```

[image: error screenshot]

Script which I am using in build.xml for creating javadocs is as follows :

```
<target name="docs" depends="compile">
    <javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
            <include name="**" />
        </fileset>
    </javadoc>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and exluding non .java files (like the .properties file) did the trick for me.

```
<javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
  <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
      <include name="**/*.java" />
  </fileset>
</javadoc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
<javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <include name="**" />
    </fileset>
</javadoc>
```

with just

```
<javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}"/>
```

Comment: Getting error : No source files and no packages have been specified.

Comment: I forgot to take `packagenames="src"` out of my reply. You should be able to get things working just with `sourcepath` and `destdir`

Comment: `<javadoc destdir="${docs.dir}" sourcepath="${src.dir}"/>` should work without any errors assuming that `${src.dir}` is the root of all your source code and is the value of the `srcdir` attribute of your call to `javac` in your `compile` target. Is there something different in your setup?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the error message! (and @ReOffender answer)

```
[javadoc] javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "E:\junoWrkspace\StrutsHelloWorld\src\com\igate\resources\ApplicationResources.properties"
```

javadoc try to generate docs from .properties files that's why javadoc doesn't find "package directive", You MUST ask your target to only generate javadoc from .java file and anything else

So @ReOffender is right:

Change your `<include name="**" />` with `<include name="**/*.java" />`